# GIT - where/how do I save my Private SSH keys?

Tags: git

I'm using Git, I want to have multiple keys.

I'm reading I should use ssh/.config.  The first thing I need to include is where to find the SSH key.

**Where do I save it?

Do I just create a .txt file and put it in a directory?**

I already have been given the private key, I need to tell Git about it somehow.

My gut it telling me (after hours of research via the mighty Google) that I need to manually create a file, not do a Git command.

**I don't want to generate a key, I can do that but I have been given one so I need to use that.**

Comment: http://superuser.com/questions/232373/how-to-tell-git-which-private-key-to-use

Comment: Are you running this on a windows machine. Because `git` has not much to do with `ssh`. `ssh` is simply a way to communicate safely with webservers (using an interactive shell).

Comment: @WillemVanOnsem Git commonly uses SSH to push/pull. HTTPS is another option, but SSH config is certainly something that can easily be important for getting Git running nicely.

Comment: Yes it's a windows machine.  and @ceejayoz is correct, I want to use SSH to communicate with my web server.

Comment: @idan Arye I have seen these types of articles many times.  Part of the config is IdentityFile ~/.ssh/id_rsa_github.  Where/how do I store id_rsa_github.